# Compare two arrays in VueJS with their ID

Tags: arrays, vue.js

I have two arrays the first array is gulod_transaction and the second is gulod_medicine. I want to compare the two arrays with there id’s to minus the quantity from the medicine table to the quantity of transaction table. The main problem is when I add the second row first from table medicine to the transaction table. And click the Save Transaction button. In my console.log it’s minus the first row which is 40 from my first table to transaction table quantity which is equal to 10 and the result becomes 30. I want to minus both quantity if they have the same id’s.

```
  for(let index = 0; index < this.gulod_transactions.length; index++) {
        if (this.gulod_transactions[index].id === this.gulod_medicines[index].medicine_id) {
            this.medicine_id = this.gulod_transactions[index].id;
            this.medicine_name = this.gulod_transactions[index].name;
            this.medicine_quantity = (parseInt(this.gulod_medicines[index].quantity) - parseInt(this.gulod_transactions[index].quantity));
            this.medicine_price = this.gulod_transactions[index].price;
            this.gulod_medicine_barangay_id = 1;

            console.log(this.gulod_medicines[index].quantity);
            console.log(this.gulod_transactions[index].quantity);
            console.log(this.medicine_quantity);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Two arrays: `a` and `b` of the shape`{id: string | number, quantity: number}[]`. I want to compare those two arrays based on their id to substract the quantity of the element in `b` from the quantity in `a`. The main problem is when I set a reference to the second element of array `a` in the first element of array `b` and click the save transaction button. 
`Help me understand this`

In my console.log it’s minus the first row which is 40 from my first table to transaction table quantity which is equal to 10 and the result becomes 30. I want to minus both quantity if they have the same id’s.

Comment: @Estradiaz 
I have two row in medicine table the first quantity is 40 and 20 quantity is 20. In transaction table I have one row with a quantity 10.. The problem is the is row in medicine table have an id of 1 while in the second table the id 2.. Which is not match. I want to minus the second in medicine table to the transaction table because the same ids which is 2

40 - 10 = 30 this is wrong. I want to minus the second row 20 with 10 with same ids